# After Quickbuild no PDF is opened automatically

Tags: viewers

I was working with Latex normally ( I use miktex and texmaker). Usually I used to click on quickbuild, then directly and automatically the pdf open in an external window. TOday, suddenly I lost this property, I open my Latex file and try quickbuild, then no pdf is open, and even I am unable to see the new pdf until I opened it from the folder where the latex file is presented.

I tried option-->configure-->pdfviewer--> embeded. In this case I see teh pdf in the same window beside the latex file. I would liek to see the pdf on an external window.

Can anyone help me solve this problem. 
Thank you in advabce.

Comment: Reinstalling Texmaker maybe helps.

Comment: I tried it, but it does not change anything

Comment: I have a video: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=yPnfHRE_W_g. from, minute 11 on you see the Texmaker configuration (including PDF viewer selection). Give it a try!

Answer (score 1):

it would help to know more info e.g. windows 10 will mess about with default pdf viewer frequently setting it back to edge.

The configure Quick Build should obviously be set to …+ ViewPDF as here
[image]

The best way to reinforce the choice of external viewer is to select it here however **note you have to add %.pdf after a space**

[image]